# nginx re-direct to API server in EC2

Tags: apache-httpd, nginx, http, reverse-proxy

I have an EC2 server (in Private subnet) from where I run some Python microservice. From my application running on an Apps EC2 (in public subnet) I am trying to access the Python microservices.

I setup nginx as reverse proxy on Apps EC2 (public subnet) . From my minimal understanding of nginx I added a conf file as below :

```
server {

        listen   80;
        server_name 3.23.xxx.xxx EC2-public.test.com;

        location / {
                root   /var/www/Myapp/App;
                index  index.php index.html index.htm;
                autoindex on;  
        }
        #Application APIs on EC2 public 
        location /api {
                proxy_pass http://myappsip-EC1.:4000;
        }

        #My second EC2 Python microservice APIs
        location /pyserv {
                proxy_pass http://myprivateEC2-IP:5000/;
         }

}
```

The issue is that from my public url I am able to access the service on the microservice EC2 if I give the absolute path in proxy_pass but any path relative to it I am not able to access. Any relative path seems to be picked by from the Primary EC2s root path.

```
=> EC2-public.test.com/ (primary application - works)
=> EC2-public.test.com/pyserv      (API1 on second EC2 - http://myprivateEC2-IP:5000/- works since given in proxy_pass) 
=> EC2-public.test.com/pyserv/srv1 (API 2 on second EC2 - http://myprivateEC2-IP:5000/srv1 - does not work)
```

I know I am missing something in that I don't seem to have referred to the second EC2 root path. But I am not able to figure out how.

Thanks

Comment: my guess is you forgot a slash. Should be `location /pyserv/`

Comment: Thank you that was the issue . If you can put it as answer I can approve it. Sincerely appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a slash at the end of `location /pyserv/` :)